# Shouldn't daily mail notifications arrive based on local timezone instead of UTC?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, timezone

I get a bunch of daily mail notifications from Stack Overflow at 3 AM (I live in Brazil). This is the only site I have subscriptions which does that. Because of Stack Overflow solely, I need to put my phone in silent mode every night.

Doesn't it make sense for daily subscriptions to arrive at 3 PM instead of 3 AM? Shouldn't they be based on local time?

Comment: I sympathize, but: you get **no** other mail during overnight hours? How have you managed that?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I have subscriptions with other sites, for example, the codeproject newsletter, programming mailing lists, or any other daily notifications, never had such weird behavior as this of SO...

Comment: Move to the UK. Problem solved. ;P